# php encoding url parameters with lowercase letters

Tags: php, url, encryption

I am struggling with encrypting url parameters. I have for example the following urls:

http://www.domain.com/show_user.php?uid=45&s=photos

http://www.domain.com/show_user.php?uid=454&s=information

Now I do not want users to see the plain values of parameters 'uid' and 's' so I encrypted them with base64_encode.

http://www.domain.com/show_user.php?uid=NDU=&s=cGhvdG9z

http://www.domain.com/show_user.php?uid=NDU0&s=aW5mb3JtYXRpb24=

But now I have the problem that I have some capital letters in the URL. I my error log I find errors which are caused by requesting the url with only lowercase letters:

http://www.domain.com/show_user.php?uid=ndu=&s=cghvdg9z

This leads to an error since the string cannot be decrypted anymore.

This obviously isn't a very smart solution to encrypt parameters in url. What would you suggest? What encrypting methods do you use? Which one only creates lowercase letters?

I already want to thank you very much in advance for any help :)

Best regards,

Freddy

Comment: base64 encoding is **not** encryption

Comment: Anyone who may be interested in those URL values will recognize the base64 *encoding* and will decode it in a heartbeat. Anybody else won't care. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: just curious: `In my error log I find errors which are caused by requesting the url with only lowercase letters` - what errors are these?

Comment: May sound stupid, and I agree with @SeanBright but you can do base32, all lowercase, might fix your issue quickly...

Comment: Maybe if you showed the code that is generating these URLs we might be able to offer more than speculation. Also, base64 encoding is even further from encryption than hashing.

Comment: Doing so would not enforce any security constraints you might seem to have assumed. It is not worth doing so.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I now realized that I made a big mistake there ... So what encrypt-function can I use to really secure my values? edit: the reason why I did this is first that I wanted to secure the values and second to not have any trouble with speific charaters that are not submitted right via url.

Comment: @Freddy : personally I wouldn't pass them as parameters, if they needed to be really secure. The parameters which are supplied as a querystring generally serve as references like an `id` in a database that refers to a row in a database table, using this `id`, we can access the corresponding row from that table, if it is allowed to be accessed by a particular user (hiding the `id` itself is essentially not needed at all).

Comment: What is your definition of "secure"? Why are those values secret? Who or what are you trying to protect them from?

Answer (score 0):

There must be a `strtolower()` in your code somewhere, addresses don't lowercase themselves. Check the code around where you're generating these encoded strings.

Also - As mentioned in that comment, it's not encryption. Functionally, is this something that actually needs to be encrypted, or just obscured?

Comment: This should have been posted as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I both agree and disagree with that, @dnLL. No it doesn't provide exact specific code. Yes it does address the OP's question with no BS. It may be speculative, but it is straightforward, Q: "My code fails due to lowercase encoding" A: "Stop making your URLs lowercase." Just my 2 cents!

Answer (score 0):

If you have only this two parameters I would recommend you to write yourself an coding & encoding function. You can also compress all parameters to only one and then decoding it again using split string function.

Answer (score 0):

If this information is somehow secret that you do not want to share, create table for mapping some id to this information, and generate page from these entries. But your need for encoding is not clear, so please elaborate more.